# Working on clearcase environment using eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, clearcase

Hi I am new to clearcase and eclipse. 
I want to connect to my office clearcase environment with eclipse which is installed in my home laptop. Is it possible ?
I installed ClearCase SCM adapter, but i am unable to find an option which mentions remote workspace !!!

Eclipse - Europa 3.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible only if you have the full ClearCase client installed.
Without it,  your [SCM adapter](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24024213) won't do much.
(Note: you don't have to use Eclipse3.3, it should support up to 3.6 or even 3.7)

The only other option is to use a CCRC client ([ClearCase Remote Client](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21205629)), but that supposes a [CM server](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/cm_server/c_configuring_cmserver.htm) is running, and that your office accepts incoming connection from "outside" for that specific service.
In that case, you need a [CCRC client](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_install.doc/topics/t_install_ccrc_standalone.htm) (not an SCM adapter)

Comment: Is It free ? How can i know whether CCRC server is running ?

Comment: @KK CCRC isn't free: it is part of the ClearCase product. You can check if a CM server runs by accessing, for instance: http://host_name:12080/TeamWeb/services/Team